# Issue with special characters in SQL

Tags: sql, character-encoding

I have a table as following

```
Create Table Test(Name NVARCHAR(100))

Insert Into Test(Name) values (N'ἀἁἃἄὠἀἁἃἄὠἀἁἃἄὠἀἁἃἄὠἀἁἃἄὠἀἁἃἄὠἀἁἃἄὠ1,')
Insert Into Test(Name) values (N'ἀἁἃἄὠἀἁἃἄ')
Insert Into Test(Name) values (N'Test')

Select * from ED.Test WHERE Name like N'ἀἁἃἄὠἀἁἃἄ'
```

This above Select query should return two results but now it is returning only one result.

This statement

```
Select * from ED.Test WHERE Name like '%ἀἁἃἄὠἀἁἃἄ%'
```

not returning any result.

```
Select * from ED.Test WHERE Name like N'%ἀἁἃἄὠἀἁἃἄ%'
```

returning all result.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

For special languages characters you should use **[COLLATE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258237(v=sql.80).aspx)**.

```
Select * from Test 
WHERE Name  COLLATE Greek_100_CS_AS_KS_WS_SC  like N'ἀἁἃἄὠἀἁἃἄ%'
```

**[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1797d/19/0) Demo**

For your solution I used `collation_name` `Greek_100_CS_AS_KS_WS_SC`

Below query returns all possible `collation_name`

```
SELECT *
FROM ::fn_helpcollations()
```

You can chose which `collation_name` suits you.

Comment: It didn't helped returning all result.

Comment: @PuneetKumar It return 2 rows. What's wrong with it?

Comment: I am not sure whats wrong , I am using SQL server 2008 R2 enterprise edition.

Comment: @PuneetKumar My query return row with `Test`?

Comment: I want to select only two row with having 'ἀἁἃἄὠἀἁἃἄ' char set .

Comment: From Like statement it look like simple Adding N clause and then use Like statement syntax but somehow it is not working. can you try to write a query that return only two row matching 'ἀἁἃἄὠἀἁἃἄ' char set.

Comment: @PuneetKumar Yes, I know. In your example there are 2 rows with  `ἀἁἃἄὠἀἁἃἄ` and one row wiht `TEST`. Does my query return row `test`?

Comment: Hi But i am having  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI collation not Greek_100_CS_AS_KS_WS_SC. SELECT * FROM ED.Test WHERE CHARINDEX(N'ἀἁἃἄὠἀἁἃἄ',Name) > 0 this will work but can we assume Like operator is not working as wild card search on special characters

Comment: @PuneetKumar - If you have language specific characters you need to compare them with appropriate collation when using `LIKE` as Parado mentioned.

Comment: @PuneetKumar It's not possible for this  special characters

Comment: Even `CHARINDEX` will give you incorrect results without collation `SELECT * FROM Test WHERE CHARINDEX(N'ἀἁἃἄὠἀἁἃἄ',Name) > 0
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE CHARINDEX(N'1ὠ',Name)  > 0
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE CHARINDEX(N'1ὠ',Name COLLATE Greek_100_CS_AS_KS_WS_SC)  > 0`

Comment: Yes , Using Greek_100_CS_AS_KS_WS collation i get the result but the issue is in my existing query i am already using COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI like ('%'+@Name+'%') ESCAPE '\' , how it is possible to amend query in such a way that it won't break the existing flow. in above query wild card is not working and hence i am getting all result instead of filtered result.

Comment: @Parodo : Thanks for your great help , but here issue is i am already using SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI .Select * from Test 
WHERE Name  COLLATE Greek_100_CS_AS_KS_WS_SC  like +'%'+@name+'%'
OR Name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI like ('%'+@name+'%') , here it always give me three result because of COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI that i don't wanna remove because it is getting used on production.

Comment: @PuneetKumar If you can't change the query - I have no idea how to help you :(.

Comment: @Parado: I got another solution like use full text search on the column where need to search special characters.

Comment: @PuneetKumar I know there is `full text search` but I've never used it on production.  It reliquaries and index on column, doesn't it? If that solution works for you can put it in an answer. I'm very curios how it works :)